# How to encrypt paypal payment redirect url from server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm developing a rails app that needs a simple payment option. I'm following this [guide](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails) to do the same. I'm generating the paypal redirect url on the server side by adding all the necessary info (like amount, reuturn_url) as GET parameters, which looks something like this

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?amount=8&business=vbc%40gmail.com&cancel=%2Fpayment%2Ffailure&cmd=_xclick&item_name=Coaching+Session&quantity=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcoaches%3Fcoach%3D76561198142767013%26hours%3D1&rm=2
```

Paypal then does a 302 redirect to another compact url like this

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=AOg4JTGaJdyUo1lOZ09-L94fNC5dVSxjDegAsAWXWW1infQOfox195rvbZi&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198ecd47ed44bac94cd6fd721232afa4155
```

which has the paypal/CreditCard payment page.

I've noticed some of the other vendors that use paypal, directly redirect to a url of the second type with SESSION, and hence not expose sensitive  parameters like amount (which can be tampered with) to the client.

How is this done ? I've looked at the paypal [REST API](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) and it seems to do a lot more than what i need.

Comment: Really depends on your needs - eg. from [Button Manager](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/button-manager/), to [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/) which uses tokens instead of passing around transaction values. Hth...

Comment: have you found the answer to this?

Comment: yes, I had to use the paypal classic api to get around it. With it, the application server(not the browser) makes an api call with the parameters like (amount, etc) and gets the final url which u can redirect the user to, which is a lot more secure.

Comment: @noobMama, how to do it? Can you show me example?